# How can I start this sum

Tags: summation, combinations, gamma-function

anyone have an idea how to find this sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_0^1 \binom{x}{n+1} \, dx$$
My trial is to transfer the integral into gamma form then  find the the integral but it's very hard also I think that may be induction could be a good idea for this

Comment: I suggested you an edit. Please check it and change the formula properly if you want an answer!

Comment: th integral is x choose n+1

Comment: You still need to edit you question as it is not correctly formatted.

Comment: You mean $\binom{x}{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes and (-1)^n-1

Comment: To correctly format it try using \binom{x}{n + 1}

Comment: See what I have edited. Is this correct?

Comment: Okay thanks alot this is right

Comment: What is the x outside the integral?

Comment: Its n i edited it

Answer (score 3):

Using the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) and the [Newton series of the Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Newton_series) we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\dbinom{x}{n+1}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\dbinom{x}{n+1}dx$$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}x\left(\psi\left(x+1\right)+\gamma-1\right)dx$$ and the integral can be calculated using integration by parts and the [Raabe's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Raabe%27s_formula)$$\int_{0}^{1}x\psi\left(x+1\right)dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)dx=1-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi\right)$$ hence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\dbinom{x}{n+1}dx=\color{red}{\frac{\gamma+1-\log\left(2\pi\right)}{2}}.$$